# how to set floating label text size?

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

I would like to change floating label text size in Android material `EditText`, when I set as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_current"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/str_current"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

It just changes the text size for hint and input Text.

Since, Floating Label Text Size seems too small in my UI, I would like to change it, any solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try following code. This may help you:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse">
```

You may use `app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"` instead.

Comment: thank you very much :) you really saved my day :) I somehow used your answer to reach my goal, but your answer lighten the true way :) I will add my answer below for others :)

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer helped me a lot to find my solution (i.e. setting the exact font size, not only using small, medium, ...).

In addition, by defining a style for app:hintTextAppearance, you can also simply set the color of floating label :)

in styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and in your TextInputLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/lyt_goal"
style="@style/CustomTextInput"
app:hintTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearance">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_goal"
    android:hint="@string/str_goal" />
```

Comment: Size and color works fine but if I am trying to change text style... nothing change.

Comment: @BajrangHudda in what way do you want to change style? give me an example. since size and color are also parts of style :-)

Comment: @par4301how about <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>? which doesn't work

Comment: Is `style=@style/CustomEditText` part of the solution? If yes: Pls post the style. If not: Remove it in order to provide a clearer answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Try The Below Code It Works In Normal State

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

     <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Hiiiii"
         android:id="@+id/edit_id"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

> In Styles Folder TextLabel Code

```
 <style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/Color Name</item> 
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/Color Name</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Color Name</item>
 </style>
```

> Set To Main Theme of App,It Works Only Highlight State Only

```
 <item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
```

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Read OP's question carefully he/she needs to set floating label size

Comment: TextInputLayout is used for floating label @NJ . That is why I put this solution. Hopefully, it will helpful !

Comment: thank you Rahul, I used that before asking the question, but unfortunately the same as I asked in the main question, it just make changes to size of hint text and input text, I want to change floating label text size, when it gets small and moves to the top of editText.

Comment: What if I want style only for hint not for real text that is in Edittext.