# changing text size all over activity, but labels of TextInputLayout are not affected

Tags: java, android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I'm trying to change font all over my application. I couldn't find any solution, but I'm doing this activity by activity.

So I've written one function, which takes a view and if it's of certain view-type (text dervative), I set the text-size to my desired font size.

But I'm having one issue with `TextInputLayout`. I can't increase their font size no matter what.

My solution:

```java
public static void setFontSize(View view, int fontSize) {
        if (view == null) {
            return;
        }

//        if (view instanceof TextInputLayout) {
//             ??? what am i supposed to do here ???
//        } else
        if (view instanceof MaterialButton) {
            ((MaterialButton) view).setTextSize(fontSize);
        } else if (view instanceof MaterialAutoCompleteTextView) {
            ((MaterialAutoCompleteTextView) view).setTextSize(fontSize);
        } else if (view instanceof AutoCompleteTextView) {
            ((AutoCompleteTextView) view).setTextSize(fontSize);
        } else if (view instanceof MaterialRadioButton) {
            ((MaterialRadioButton) view).setTextSize(fontSize);
        } else if (view instanceof Button) {
            ((Button) view).setTextSize(fontSize);
        } else if (view instanceof TextInputEditText) {
            ((TextInputEditText) view).setTextSize(fontSize);
        } else if (view instanceof MaterialTextView) {
            ((MaterialTextView) view).setTextSize(fontSize);
        } else if (view instanceof AppCompatTextView) {
            ((AppCompatTextView) view).setTextSize(fontSize);
        } else if (view instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) view).setTextSize(fontSize);
        } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
            for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
                setFontSize(group.getChildAt(i), fontSize);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Somehow those labels are not being processed under this, so I can't set their type. Can you guys help me fix it?**

I've already seen these solutions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35203711/10305444
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409950/10305444
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35738706/10305444

But they don't help me. (As they are providing static like solution, but I want to make it pure dynamic)